# Getting lastname from email using regex replace option

Tags: regex

I would like to get lastname from an email address:

Sample:

```
don.jane@marketing.com -> jane
john.bell@apple.com -> bell
```

I have tried this

```
(.*)@.*
```

Replace

```
$1
```

Which gives me:

```
john.bell
```

NOTE: I have to use replace option

Thanks for your help

Comment: *NOTE: I have to use replace option* - why? Try [`^.*\.([^@.]+)@.*$`](https://regex101.com/r/DI75zd/1).

Answer (score 1):

Get all word characters before the following `@` sign:

```
\w+(?=@)
```

[See it in action](https://regex101.com/r/GuiSDD/3)

---

If for some reason you really want to use replace you could do:

```
\w+\.|@.*
```

Replace with empty string.

[See it in action](https://regex101.com/r/GuiSDD/2)

The idea is to replace either word characters followed by a dot or everything after the `@` sign (included).